# Table column name create with empty space auto formating , why..?

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2005

I have create the column with name " Departure _Date " , but it is automatically changed into " [Departure _Date] "(Not in query using SQL Server Management studio). If i remove the empty space from the column name , there is no problem. Anyone can explain detailed..

Comment: No, the column name is just `Departure _Date` - but if you do anything that causes management studio to generate a script that refers to it, it will be quoted using `[]` marks, because otherwise the scripts will break because spaces are used to separate parts of SQL syntax

Comment: Why would you want to name your table this? You have already identified an inconvenience. There is much debate on what is the "standard" naming convention, however not one of these debates include whether or not it is a good idea to have spaces in object names; this is universally considered bad practice.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Square brackets around column names are inferred.  Even when you cannot see them they are always really there.

When using spaces in column names and certain keywords it's necessary to use square brackets more frequently when referring to columns,  including in table generation scripts and the design interface.

SELECT Departure _Date FROM myTable

For example, without the square brackets, this SQL statement would be selecting the "Departure" field and returning it with an alias of "_Date".

Even when using the column name Departure_Date, the column could be referred to as either [Departure_Date] or Departure_Date in SQL statements.